# Laravel blade pass Javascript variable in php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, variables

How can I pass a javascript variable as an variable in my php loop:

Something like this(obviously does not work):

```
        var myJsVar = 100;

        @for ($i = 0; $i<myJsVar; $i++)
            ... some code
        @endfor
```

Further I tried solving this with ajax:

```
        /**
         *  Get slider value
         */
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: myUrl,
            data: myJsVar,
            success: function (option) {
                console.log(myJsVar);
            }
        });
```

It returns me the success function,

Further I did this in my Controller:

```
public function prod(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        $ajax = "AJAX";
        dd($ajax);
    } else {
        $ajaxN = "NO Ajax";
        dd($ajaxN);
    }
}
```

It did not work.

I am not sure how to proceed, hope for some help.

Comment: From where you got the value of the `myJsVar` ? I mean it is static or come from the database or from something else ?

Comment: I simplified the code, myJsVar is a dynamic value from a slider (javascript, jquery ui slider)

Comment: To clarify, the "does not work" part means you're getting "NO Ajax" returned from the controller?

Comment: yes I get "no ajax"

Comment: The reason you're getting "No ajax" is because jQuery does not automatically set the header [which Laravel checks](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php#L216-L219). The method Laravel is calling in the link before is [one from Symfonys HTTPFoundation](https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/master/Request.php#L1680-L1683)

Answer (score 3):

PHP has finished doing its work even before the page hits your browser, so passing a variable from Javascript to PHP without doing another request is simply impossible. Consider

**A)** Moving your loop to Javascript. Consider using some UI library like [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/), [Angular](https://angularjs.org/) or [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/).

**B)** Move the contents of `myJsVar` to PHP. If it depends on user input or browser rendering, that impossible.

**C)** Performing the rendering logic through an Ajax-request

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: myUrl,
            headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'},
            data: {value: myJsVar},
            success: function (response) {
                $(someContainer).html(response);
            }
        });
```

And in your controller:

```
public function prod()
{
   $value =  Request::get('value');

   return view('view-with-a-loop')->with('value', $value);
}
```

Be careful with the latter method XSS-wise.

Comment: My loop is actually inside my Javascript like this `<script>var bla;<?php ...  ?></script> `If you mean it like that, the content of myJsVar is created by a slider

Comment: Thanks I will check it out

Comment: Ok if I `dd(value)` I get null

Comment: Try `{ value : "foo" }` in the JS, just to see if it's failing php- or js-side

Comment: If I change it to "foo" dd(value) returns me null

Comment: My Ajax success function works so I guess it's failing php side

Comment: Just out of interest, how do you inspect what is `dd`'ed? In the network tab?

Comment: I just dd the value, it automatically exits after dd, I could also do a basic print_r(value);exit; I just look at the output on the page not in the network tab

Comment: Whether you visit the URL in your browser or you're inspecting the actual ajax-request? Try `dd`'ing `Request::all()`.

Comment: I visit the url in my browser `dd(Request::all())` prints me an empty array

Comment: If you visit the URL in your browser, you're not sending anything. If you have to test it like that, you'll have to say `http://my/url?value=example-slider-value`

Comment: ok if I `http://my/url?value=2` it prints my this array:`Array
(
    [value] => 2
)`, I understand but how do I go further

Comment: one cannot not return  a view with ajax just a json response or not?

Answer (score 1):

I use a section in blade to add the javascript then pull that into the layout. The example below shows passing of integer/string/collection of models, eg:

// blade template

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('javascript')

<script type="text/javascript">
    var myInteger = {!! $myInteger !!};
    var myString = '{!! $myInteger !!}';
    var myObject = {!! json_encode($models) !!};
</script>

@endsection

@section('content')
...
@endsection
```

// Layout (the javascript can go anywhere in the layout, ie the head or body:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    @yield('content')
    @yield('javascript')
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Caveat: This doesn't help if you are trying to inject a variable into an ESM. Also, if you use an automatic code formatter (and why wouldn't you), your formatter is probably going to break your code.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do it is to render your value into a `meta` tag, like so:

`<meta name="myJsVar" content="100">`

Then use JavaScript to read that value via DOM:

`var myJsVar = parseInt(document.querySelector("meta[name=myJsVar]").content);`