# Fullcalendar 3 change draggable events when changing week

Tags: javascript, laravel, fullcalendar

I work with fullcalendar 3 with laravel.

The draggable events are courses and should be different every week. I want to dynamically change the courses when I change the week in the calendar.

At the moment in the controller I have a function that give me every course:

```
public function index()
    {
        $corsi = Corso::select('titolo', 'descrizione','ore_45esimi')->get();
        return view('lezione.calendario_lezioni')->with(array('corsi' => $corsi));
    }
```

then in the view I display the events using a div:

```
<div id="external-events">
  @foreach($corsi as $corso)
    <div class="external-event bg-formazione">{{$corso->titolo }}
      <br>
      <div style="font-size: small">{{$corso->descrizione }} </div>
      <input id="ore" type="hidden" value="{{$corso->ore_45esimi }}">
    </div>
   @endforeach
 </div>
```

And in the Fullcalendar js file I have a function to make the courses draggable:

```
    function ini_events(ele) {
            ele.each(function () {
                let eventObject = {
                    title: $(this).contents()
                        .filter(function () {
                            return !!$.trim(this.innerHTML || this.data);
                        })
                        .first().text(),

                    descrizione: $.trim($(this).contents()[3].firstChild.textContent),
                    ore: $(this).contents('#ore').val(),
                    color: $(this).css("background-color"), 
                };
                $(this).data('event', eventObject);

                $(this).draggable({
                    zIndex: 1070,
                    revert: true, 
                    revertDuration: 0  
                });

            });
        }

ini_events($('#external-events div.external-event'));
```

I found the viewRender function that allow me to get the begin and the end of the displayed week:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
...

viewRender: function (element) {
            var start = moment(element.intervalStart).format();
            var end = moment(element.intervalEnd).subtract(1, 'd').format();

        },
});
```

How can I use the start and end variable into the index method in the controller's query when I first show the calendar and every time I change the week?

Answer (score 0):

You wish to pass two javascripts variables in php. There is huge literature on this issue, see for example 
[Laravel blade pass Javascript variable in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38224886/laravel-blade-pass-javascript-variable-in-php)
There are many possible solutions.
I prefer pass the values of the variables through an url to a new method and after through session to the index method.
1) routes/web.php

```
Route::get('yourproject/{start}/{end}/getstartandend','yourController@getstartandend');
```

2) view

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
...

viewRender: function (element) {
        var start = moment(element.intervalStart).format();
        var end = moment(element.intervalEnd).subtract(1, 'd').format();

    },
});
...
appBase="{!!URL::to('/')!!}";
var route = appBase + "/yourproject/"+start+"/"+end+"/getstartandend"; 
$.get(route);
```

3) yourController

```
 public function index ()
 {
    $corsi = Corso::select('titolo', 'descrizione','ore_45esimi')->get();
    return view('lezione.calendario_lezioni')->with(array('corsi' => $corsi));
$start = session('start');
$end = session('end');
....
  }

 public function getstartandend ($start, $end)
{
 session(['start' => $start]);
 session(['end' => $end]);
}
```