# How can I access JSON passed from PHP Laravel it in JS?

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel, laravel-blade

## View

Right now, when I do

`<pre>{{ $device->window }}</pre>`

I see this

[image]

---

I want to access it in JS. Ex. `device.screen.height`, It's `926`

I've tried

```
console.log(`{{ json_decode($device->window) }}`);
console.log(JSON.parse(`{{ json_decode($device->window) }}`));
console.log(JSON.parse(`{{ json_decode($device->window) }}`));
console.log(JSON.stringify(`{{ json_decode($device->window) }}`));
console.log(JSON.stringify(`{{ json_decode($device->window) }}`));
console.log(JSON.parse(`{{ json_encode($device->window) }}`));
console.log(JSON.parse(`{{ json_encode($device->window) }}`));
console.log(JSON.stringify(`{{ json_encode($device->window) }}`));
console.log(JSON.stringify(`{{ json_encode($device->window) }}`));
```

I kept getting

> htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

---

If I do :

console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(`{{ json_encode($device->window) }}`)));

I got

`&quot;{&quot;innerWidth&quot;:&quot;980&quot;,&quot;innerHeight&quot;:&quot;1708&quot;,&quot;devicePixelRatio&quot;:&quot;3&quot;,&quot;screen&quot;:{&quot;width&quot;:&quot;428&quot;,&quot;height&quot;:&quot;926&quot;}}&quot;`

I got so many `&quot;`

Comment: Decode makes it useable for PHP, encode allows you to pass it to javascript as a string. Since it's already encoded, don't mess with it on the PHP side

Comment: PHP side, I passed it to JS (FE) as is. Let me try encoding then. If you know the right syntax please feel free to suggest.

Comment: I would suggest you not to do that. It is not a common nor good practice. Mixing languages usually end up bad. Better to get the data in another way like AJAX. But if you insists, you may do some good with json encode and decode

Comment: I am using Laravel blade, it's the details page of my device. In that I already have access to `$device` object base on id.

Comment: I can access any attribute like `$device->propertyName` I don't need to do another AJAX for that.

Comment: What happens when you try `console.log(JSON.parse('$device->window'))`? Assuming that line is generated by PHP, it should stick the JSON string inside single quotes, resulting in a string that Javascript can use with `JSON.parse()`, e.g. `console.log('{"foo":"bar","baz":"bat"}')`.

Comment: The device is the client side, why dont you get the info about the device from the js directly ? `var width = (window.innerWidth > 0) ? window.innerWidth : screen.width;`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the device width in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850164/get-the-device-width-in-javascript)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel blade pass Javascript variable in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38224886/laravel-blade-pass-javascript-variable-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use different sintax for that :

```
{!! json_encode($device->window) !!}
```

But you should not access it like this. Its not good practice to mix languages.

Comment: YOUR suggestion works perfectly on first try, may I know this support on all Laravel version ? Can you please attach a ref link, so I can read more about it.

Comment: How do I access my height ? .screen.height not working.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#displaying-unescaped-data Enjoy ! @code8888

Comment: please acept my answer if it worked for you so topic will be closed @code8888

Comment: Here is answer for screen height : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437786/get-the-size-of-the-screen-current-web-page-and-browser-window

Answer (score 1):

Inside a script tag, you could do:

```
const myData = {{ $device->window }};
console.log(myData.screen.height);
```

Comment: `let` may suit `$device->window` better than `const`, as these are not constant values. PHP will deliver only the initial value anyway - therefore the whole question is kind of questionable.

Comment: its all explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437786/get-the-size-of-the-screen-current-web-page-and-browser-window

Answer (score 0):

The's a blade directive for that:

```php
@php
    $json = [ 1, new DateTime, (object)[], 'a' ];
@endphp
<script>
    test = @json($json);
    console.log(test)
</script>
```